# Check if string starts with prefix list in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to check in KQL (Kusto Query Language) if a string starts with any prefix that is contained in a list.

Something like:

```
let MaxAge = ago(30d);
let prefix_list = pack_array(
    'Mr',
    'Ms',
    'Mister',
    'Miss'
);
| where Name startswith(prefix_list)
```

I know this example can be done with `startswith("Mr","Ms","Mister","Miss")` but this is not escalable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an *inefficient* but functional option would be using `matches regex` - this can work well if the input data set is not too large:

```
let T = datatable(Name:string)
[
    "hello" ,'world', "Mra", "Ms 2", "Miz", 'Missed'
]
;
let prefix_list = pack_array(
    'Mr',
    'Ms',
    'Mister',
    'Miss'
);
let prefix_regex = strcat("^(", strcat_array(prefix_list, ")|("), ")");
T
| where Name matches regex prefix_regex
```

| Name |
| --- |
| Mra |
| Ms 2 |
| Missed |

Answer (score 2):

This function is not available in the Kusto query language, you are welcome to open a suggestion for it in the [user feedback form](http://aka.ms/kustouservoice)